# Simple app to run WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've just written a new WPF UserControl. Now I want to try it out. What's the easiest program I can write to run it?

---

So far I have

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var grid = new CorrelationsGrid();
    }
}
```

But the application runs and closes immediately without showing my control on screen. Help!

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: @DavidPilkington yes of course

Comment: Then my answer will work for you.

Comment: Did it work for you? @Colonel Panic

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio

Select File -> New -> Project...

Select WPF application.

Then add your user control to the project.

Finally in the XAML, add your UserControl to the MainWindow.xaml and it will handle all of the displaying for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:myuct="clr-namespace:namespaceofyourusercontrol"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <myuct:myusercontrol/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: your solution saved me. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Create a new WPF application, and put it in the Grid in the MainWindow.xaml. Of course this assumes "easiest" to mean "least hassle", rather than "minimalist".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way should be this.

Once you written your control and you built it, the control will be part of your 'Toolbox', that means a window where all the available controls are visible and grouped.

You can use Visual Studio to add your control, from the 'Toolbox' window, to your MainWindow, in an empty WPF project.
This will add few lines of code in your MainWindow.xaml file, about your control.

Now you can customize the properties of your user control, like any other control.